# Need a verification code for Visual Studio Online Migration Utility

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am installing the OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility, and teh email with verification code never arrived. I tried 2 different networks, and tried a corporate and personal email account with no success. I emailed support, but the autoresponser requests that a posting be made on Stack Overflow with the #opshub and #visual-studio-online tags. If OpsHub support read this, can yo please respond with an email verification code please.

Comment: The verification code email system works fine now, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as you. I hope OpsHub support can help us resolve it.

Additionally, instead of using the OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility, would you consider using [TFS Integration Platform](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) at the present? You can use it to migrate version control and work-item/bug tracking from on-premise TFS to VSO.